# How to implement in-app purchases correctly?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

### How can i implement in-app purchases in my application?

I want to disable ads if the user paid me.

---

I spend a lot of hours to figure how it works by looking for tutorials.
I saw all the lectures on youtube about that.
I read on google developer site:http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_admin.html
I saw some example codes.
So,
I understood the concept

I know how: 
 **1.** create new product.
 **2.** create a test account for testing.
 **3.** publish my application to beta/alpha.

So,my question is:
 
What should I do in code?
How to manage it correctly?
 
If user paid money for removing the ads how the application know if to show him the ads or not?
Do i need to save the data locally manage it with SharedPreference or i getting the status about his purchases automatically?
 What will happen if the user replace his device?
Google remember his account and his purchases?
 
I really need a basic example :(.
 
Like few methods that make 
 "**buy()**"
  and 
 "**isOwned()**"
  for checking if the current user has paid ..

***Help me please***

Comment: in oncreate check if the user has earlier purchases using mReceivedInventoryListener, once you confirmed via like inventory.hasPurchase(ITEM_SKU_PREMIUM) then remove ads, else show ads. The user needs to be logged in via same account he bought earlier.

Answer (score 0):

First of all implement In-app purchase in your application, you can follow [this](https://github.com/blundell/SimpleInAppPurchaseV3) link.

When user purchased any item successfully, success status will be sent from google.

After purchasing successfully, store some flag value in `SharedPreferences`, `SQLiteDatabase` or in your server database through webservices.

Now whenever you are showing ads in your application, check flag value you have stored.

1. if flag shows that user have purchased item, don't show ads.

2. if flag value shows that user did not purchase anything show your ads.

> Google remember his account and his purches?

Google will fetch all purchases from user's email id. You can restore purchase from the user, so whenever user uninstalls your app and you dont want user to purchase your item again, give them option of restore. Restore will give their product back and also give you success status.

Comment: Thanks but i saw the link you sent me. That example has a lot of code that i don't think i need. My question was what the basic method i need to integrate it correctly